# Call the canvas image to another div or page

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

Can anybody help me with this I'm solving this problem for almost a week and never get success. I want to happen is to call the image that was been created the image goes to "image" in a div and I want to call that image to the another page but No image show. Please take a look my code.

```
     <script>
          function myFunction(){
          html2canvas([document.getElementById('card-container')], {
          onrendered: function (canvas) {

         var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');


 // AJAX call to send `data` to a PHP file that creates an image from the dataURI string and saves it to a directory on the server

          var image = new Image();
          image.src =  data;

         document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);

         }
          });
         }
          </script>

          <button onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>

          <div id="image">
          <p>Image:</p>
          </div>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="sample.com" method="post" onsubmit="this.divcontent.value = document.getElementById('image').innerHTML;" >
            <input type="hidden" name="image" id="divcontent" value="" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
```

> Here is the ready-image.php

```
<?php
$img = $_POST['divcontent'];
echo "<img src='$img' alt='image' />";

 define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'wp-content/uploads/2014/03/');
$img = $_POST['img'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';   
           ?>
```

> Please help me guys. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just to clarify a bit, are you trying to submit the image to `ready-image.php` in base64 format, and display the image (with a button to download it) after the submission?

Comment: yes sir thats what I'm trying to do. But no success :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want. Since the ajax part is missing from your code, I am just trying to pass the image captured to the `ready-image.php` and display it.

I am assuming that the codes are on 2 separate files.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        html2canvas([document.getElementById('card-container')], {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
                var image = new Image();
                image.src =  data;
                document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
                $("#divcontent").val(data); //save the image base64 string to a hidden input
            }
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="card-container">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" >Try it</button>

    <div id="image">
        <p>Image:</p>
    </div>

    <form action="ready-image.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

`ready-image.php`:

```
<?php
    $img = $_POST['divcontent'];
    echo "<img src='$img' alt='image' />";

    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'wp-content/uploads/2014/03/');

    $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
    $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
    $data = base64_decode($img);
    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
    $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
    print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.'; 
?>
```

Update:

```
<?php
    $img = $_POST['divcontent'];
    echo "<img src='$img' alt='image' />";

    define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'wp-content/uploads/2014/03/');
    $filteredData = substr($img, strpos($img, ",") + 1);
    $decodedData = base64_decode($filteredData);

    $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';

    $fp = fopen($file,'wb');
    if ($fp) {
        fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
        print $file;
    } else {
        print 'Unable to save the file.';
    }
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

I commented out the `download` part because I am not sure how exactly you call the ajax to save the file, so that part is omitted from my solution.

Comment: sir there still no image send in ready-image.php. By the way just want to clarify something sir the "card-container" is the one I convert to image so once the button "try it" was click the image will show to div "image" and I'm trying to send it to ready-image.php but nothing shows. Hope you can still help me with this sir that's I really appreciate your effort. Thank you very much.

Comment: (1) after clicking on the `Try it` button, could you see the screen capture of the `card-container` in the `image` div? (2) by using `firebug` or other element inspecting tools on the browser, could you see the value of the hidden div `divcontent` change?

Comment: yes sir the screen was captured but there is no value in the "divcontent" here is the element '<form action="ready-image.php" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="divcontent" id="divcontent">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>'

Comment: alright, I think it's because you have not included the jQuery there, while I have used jQuery. add something like `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` to your code and try again.

Comment: or change `$("#divcontent").val(data);` this line to a JS version: `document.getElementById('divcontent').value = data;`

Comment: sir one more question why is that when I saved it directly to server the image was corrupted..Sorry for disturbance..Thanks again

Comment: yes I attached it in ready-image.php 'code' define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'wp-content/uploads/2014/03/');
 $img = $_POST['img'];
 $img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
 $img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
 $data = base64_decode($img);
 $file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
 $success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
 print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';   'code'

Comment: @winresh24 I have updated the solution, please try. Your code basically works fine for me, just the line `$img = $_POST['img'];` makes no sense there and I have deleted that.

Comment: yes sir its was uploaded to server the file was corrupted or empty..why is that sir? I don't know how to thank you sir

Comment: @winresh24 so actually you could save the file and find it on the server, but the file is corrupted?

Comment: absolutely yes sir..why is that sir?

Comment: @winresh24 Could you please try my updated piece of codes and see if that works?

Comment: wooooooh!!! you really save my day sir I'll tried to figure it out for almost a week..Thank very much sir maybe it's better to call you MASTER :) Thanks again...